# Cloud9-ide, Ruby-On-Rails4, "XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: https://api.c9.io/settings/state/6148410?access_token=9cwbfW5wFe2pHewHk2u0"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

Error with Cloud9 IDE.  No one seems to have an answer or hint on cloud9 community.

Below is the error I get in the Firefox console:

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: https://api.c9.io/settings/state     
/6148410?access_token=9cwbfW5wFe2pHewHk2u0
```

Does anyone have any idea of where to start with this???  Thank you.

EDIT:

I realized this is probably a routing issue - is this due to using devise?

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :pages
namespace :users do
devise_for :users
root to: 'devise/sessions#new'
match 'sessions/new' => 'devise/sessions#new', via:[:get, :post]
match 'pages/new' => 'pages#new', via:[:get, :post]
match 'pages/new' => 'pages#create', via:[:get, :post]
match 'pages/show' => 'pages#show', via:[:get, :post]
match 'pages/index' => 'pages#index', via:[:get, :post]

end
```

Comment: IMHO it makes perfect sense that you get an XML parsing error because that URL returns JSON not XML.

Comment: OK, might there be any way I would mess something up so that my rails app returns xml????  I have explored settings...  Ohhh OK so now I have realized this is a routing issue.  I suppose I routing to XML with devise?  Please check edit.